# Jquery html tag replace

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to replace, with Jquery, this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<div class="under">
    <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
</ul>
```

Parent element is: `<ul id="menu">`

Comment: Why don't you change the CSS class of the parent and make the ul / li work as div  / p tags?
PS: On the second code snipet, the div tag is closed with a </ul> tag.

Comment: Becouse, i use wordpress menu nav, and menu has lava menu javascript efects, the second level of menu use div structure, if i change wordpress menu functions to div structure, menu dont working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could unwrap the `a` element and then wrap it in the new elements:

```
$(".sub-menu").find("a").unwrap().unwrap().wrap("<div class='under'>").wrap("<p>");
```

The two calls to `unwrap` remove the `li` and then the `ul`, and the two calls to `wrap` add the `div` and the `p`. Note that we have to wrap the `div` first, then the `p`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/J5R7N/) (inspect the DOM in the results window to see what you end up with).

Note that I'm assuming the closing `ul` was meant to be a closing `div` tag in your second example!

**Edit**

You could also combine the two calls to `wrap`, which should be faster:

```
$(".sub-menu").find("a").unwrap().unwrap().wrap("<div class='under'><p></p></div>");
```

**Another edit**

Using `unwrap` twice seemed a little messy to me. Now that I've had a little spare time I've thrown together a simple plugin that allows you to unwrap multiple ancestor elements from a target element. I've called it [`unwrapUntil`, and you can find it on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesallardice/jquery.unwrapuntil). It will work for any number of unwraps, and using it in this specific case would probably be a bit extreme, but it would allow us to do the following:

```
$(".sub-menu").find("a").unwrapUntil(2).wrap("<div class='under'><p></p></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the replace with but you would  need to build up the html eg:

```
$('li').replaceWith('<p><a href="#">Link</a></p>');
```

[JQuery Ref](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newdiv = $("<div></div>")
newdiv.addClass("under")
$(".sub-menu a").each(function(){
    newdiv.append("<p></p>").find("p:last").append(this)
})
$(".sub-menu").replaceWith(newdiv)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QLkS5/